# Merge the array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem to combine two arrays.

Two array like this

```
$a=array("291387","054645","290981");
$a1=array("245354","232145","23556");
```

Need to merge array like this

`array("291387","054645","290981","245354","232145","23556")`

and also merge the array like

`array('cent'=> "291387","054645","290981","245354","232145","23556")`

Thanks

Comment: use $data['cent'] = array_merge($a,$a1); simple

Comment: Thanks. One more array to merge $data['cent'] like $a2 = array("291387","054645","290981");

Comment: array_merge($a,$a1,$a3);

Comment: don't forget to upvote and accept the right answer @sathish

Comment: Thanks one more question

Comment: Thanks one more question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161851/discussion-between-sathish-and-kunal).

Comment: if you think my answer was helpful please accept by clicking on checkmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple try this:-

```
$a=array("291387","054645","290981");
$a1=array("245354","232145","23556");
$data['cent'] = array_merge($a,$a1);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=array("291387","054645","290981");
$a1=array("245354","232145","23556");
$add = array_merge($a, $a1);
$result = array('cent'=>$add);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```